# Workflow foundation: edit activity arguments

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I need to create Activity Designer where I can edit its arguments.
I have an Activity that loads another activity XAML through its location path.

```
 [Designer(typeof(LoadSubTreeActivityDesigner))]
        public class LoadSubTree : NativeActivity
        {...}
```

In activity designer I load View and Viewmodel that represent my Activity:

```
 <sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="Cellebrite.Diagnostics.WF.Activities.Designers.LoadSubTreeActivityDesigner"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
                      xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Cellebrite.Diagnostics.WF.Activities.Common">
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource {x:Static common:Constants.SubTreeLoadingDataTemplate}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowExpanded,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type sap:ActivityDesigner}}}" />
</sap:ActivityDesigner>
```

Designer looks this way:
[image]

Command "Open Editor" on screenshot shows dialog to edit arguements:

[image]

This is the code how to open this Editor Dialog I've found in internet:

```
  public ICommand DefineArgsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(param =>
            {
                ModelItem model = param as ModelItem;
                var options = new DynamicArgumentDesignerOptions()
                {
                    Title = "Edit Arguments"
                };

                var modelItem = model.Properties["Arguments"]?.Dictionary;
                using (ModelEditingScope change = modelItem.BeginEdit("ChildArgumentEditing"))
                {
                    if (DynamicArgumentDialog.ShowDialog(model, modelItem, model.GetEditingContext(), model.View, options))
                    {
                        change.Complete();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        change.Revert();
                    }
                }

            }, param => true);
        }
    }
```

However, I need to represent these Arguments inside of Designer:
[image]

This dialog is part of MS `System.Activities.Core.Presentation.dll` and all sub classes are internal or private.
Does someone know how to add arguments to `model.Properties["Arguments"]?.Dictionary` manually beside usage of `DynamicArgumentDialog`?
I couldn't recognize what types this object expect to receive and I receive run time exception when I try different variations.

**Does someone know how to edit arguments in alternative way?**